# Subtract number from enum

Tags: mysql, sql

My `number` column in `data` table has enum values:

`1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105`

I want to set values of `number = number - 100` for all rows using query:

`UPDATE data SET data.number = (data.number - 100) WHERE data.number > 100`

But it does not work on enum data.

Comment: Please add the SQL to create the table, so we can reproduce the case.

Comment: Hehe, I recognize these values. This should not be enum. You need to normalize it. Close types should be a separate table.

Comment: "But it does not work" -- **Exactly how does it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little complicated.

Mysql doesn'z allow number to be cast from ENUM, because the says that numbers should not be used as [ENUM value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html#enum-limits).

but as you need the value if the ENUM field you can convert it into characters.

The final step is to convert that text into a number.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data` (   

  number ENUM('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '101', '102', '103', '104', '105')  
 ) ;

INSERT INTO `data` VALUES ( '103');

UPDATE `data` SET number = CAST(CAST(`number` AS CHAR) AS UNSIGNED)  - 100 WHERE CAST(CAST(`number` AS CHAR) AS UNSIGNED) >= 100;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM `data`;

| number |
| ------ |
| 3      |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I know I should use integers in database, but at this point it is impossible to rewrite all queries and database for one operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do arithmetic operations on cardinal numbers (integer, float, double, decimal, date). An enum datatype is nominal.

You could try casting it within SQL but if this operation should be possible the issue is that you have chosen the wrong data type.

That you are exclusively using digits to represent states should have been a red flag.

Comment: yes, mysql is subtracting index not number from data. like (101 - 1) [index=6] return 5 [index=5]. I want to subtract 100 if possible. 101=1, 102=2, 103=3... and so on...

Comment: ITS NOT POSSIBLE

Answer (score 0):

> But it does not work on enum data.

Of course. The string values of ENUM datatype are not the values stored in table data body - it contains 2-byte index of the value only, and according string values list is stored in table definition area which is not available for changing by any DML operation. Only DDL (ALTER TABLE) may change ENUM value string representation definition.

The posted query will treate `data.number` as index value - so you must get the error (source values are 1-10, final values will be negative whereas ENUM index values are UNSIGNED).

Comment: yes, mysql is subtracting index not number from data. like (101 - 1) [index=6] return 5 [index=5]. I want to subtract 100 if possible. 101=1, 102=2, 103=3... and so on...